# Como pegar um valor entre colchete na string?

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho uma string que vai variar os valores, preciso pegar os valores dentro do [],

```
{"time_zones":[]}
```

No caso estaria vazia, ela poderá vir preenchida:

```
{"time_zones":[teste]}
```

Estou tentando fazer assim

```
 var palavras = a.Split('[');
 var palavra = palavras[1];
```

Porém ele me retorna o resto do código: `]}`
No caso se não tivesse nada, o valor era vazio, caso fosse preenchido eu precisava do teste. (esse valor varia);

Comment: Você pode fazer assim... mas se a sua string é um deseralizável como parece, existem outras abordagens para isso

Comment: Conseguir resolver @LeandroAngelo, obrigado.

Comment: Tratando como string ou Json?

Comment: String, fiz dessa forma   string[] split = a.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' });
            MessageBox.Show(split[1]);

Comment: Aceitaria um Regex? você está tentando pegar a palavra teste?

Comment: Sim eu preciso pegar a palavra teste, porém nem sempre vai ter esta palavra, inclusive pode conter outros caracteres, e várias palavras.

Comment: @marianac_costa adicionei regex a sua pergunta, você disse que poderia ser :)

Comment: trata como json que é melhor....

Comment: Definitivamente o [comentário do @RovannLinhalis é a linha a seguir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306818/como-pegar-um-valor-entre-colchete-na-string#comment622636_306818). Isso é um json, tratá-lo como tal vai facilitar a vida. Não vale a pena mirabolar uma solução desse tipo, a manutenção vai cobrar caro.

Comment: Uma hora vai chegar um `{"time_zones":[teste, teste2]}` para bagunçar o meio de campo (=C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com o REGEX `"\[(.*)\]"`

- `\[` Escape é  necessário para ser tratado como texto e não como um conjunto.
- `.*` Procure por nenhuma ou várias ocorrências.
- No `C#` pegue o primeiro Grupo, será onde está a palavra `teste`(demonstrada no segundo exemplo) ou qualquer coisa que esteja entre os colchetes.

<sup>[***Funcionando em dotnetfiddle***](https://dotnetfiddle.net/61yO9B)</sup>

```
 using System;
    using static System.Console;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;                       
        public class Program {
            public static void Main() {
                string texto = "{\"time_zones\":[teste]}";
                Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[(.*)\]");
                Console.Write(rgx.Match(texto).Groups[1]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de um método do controller, faz

```
public string GetMinhaString()
{
    string tuaString = @"{ ""time_zones"": [ ""teste"", ""zero"", ""um"" ] }";

    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeuObjeto>(tuaString);

    return string.Join("-", o.time_zones) + ", total de " + o.time_zones.Length ;
}
```

e declara uma classe privada, dentro do controller, da seguinte forma,

```
private class MeuObjeto
{
    public string[] time_zones { get; set; }
}
```

Dessa forma, vais obter a informação que precisa e tipada de acordo com o JSON fornecido.

Comment: Já sei que a @marianac_costa está a usar ASP.NET Core